# Unable to find pmrep command when using Linux and Jenkins Set up (followed all the suggestions)

Tags: jenkins, informatica

I am new to jenkins set up. Right now I am trying to run informatica pmrep commands through Jenkins job.
I have done the below steps -

- I made a simple script(has only pmrep command in it), when I am running it from Linux, its running fine. When running from Jenkins failing with same error, i.e PMREP command not found.
- I gave absolute path of pmrep file as well in script but still its failing with same error.
- I searched in the folder where informatica is installed in the linux machine and the pmrep file and can see the same path, which have been provided in the path of script as well.

Note - all the required path have been set up in .bash_profile file(domains.infa path as well) and also in Jenkins global configuration (just to be on safe side).

The exact error Jenkins throwing is as below -
/data/FDR/Scripts/test.sh: Line 5: pmrep: Command not found

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved, while calling the file from Linux box, I also need to use below steps -

source /home//.bash_profile
/pmrep

and it will work fine.